# how can i improve my code so that it doesn't show timeout error

Tags: python, median

when i am calculating median in python using the code below it's showimg timeout error.

```
import os
import sys
import math
def runningMedian(a):
    result=[]
    l=[]
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        l.append(a[i])
        l.sort()
        if len(l)==1:
            result.append(float(l[0]))
        elif len(l)%2==0:
            d=math.ceil(len(l)/2)
            result.append(float(l[d-1]+l[d])/2)
        elif len(l)%2!=0:
           result.append(float(l[math.floor(len(l)/2)]))
    return result
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @blhsing but when i am running it on hackerrank ,this is showing timeout error.

Comment: I see. It's a performance/efficiency issue then.

Comment: First of all, try to reduce the time complexity. You are currently doing `l.sort` in each step of the loop. That is `O(n^2 log n)`. Although the solution is probably correct, it is not good enough, because the whole task is to come out with a smarter solution, which does not have to do all that. Note that at the point where you do `l.append` and `l.sort`, the list is already sorted, except for the last element. Take advantage of that.

Comment: also avoid naming something `l`, esp for hackerrank

Comment: just in case anyone interested in the challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-the-running-median/problem